# How to install Flutter for all users on Linux?

Tags: linux, installation, flutter

I want to install the Flutter SDK on an Ubuntu system for all users.  However, e.g. https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux shows me how to do that only for a specific user.  Since Flutter needs *a lot* of disk space, I would prefer installing it like any other program in `/usr` or `/opt`.

But how does one do that?  Apparently, Flutter needs write permissions to the directories where it was installed to at run time, and I need to avoid making the directories world-writable.

Answer (score 0):

From [the guide you linked t](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux)o:

```
cd /opt

wget https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_2.10.1-stable.tar.xz

tar xf flutter_linux_2.10.1-stable.tar.xz

cd flutter/bin

pwd
```

Then add the location of `flutter/bin` to the PATH variable in `/etc/profile`.

Comment: And e.g. a `flutter doctor --android-licenses` works for you this way? FWIW, for me, `/opt/flutter` needs to be writable for the respective user.

Comment: If `/opt/flutter` needs to be written to, then create a group like `flutter-group` and then assign users to that group and make that the default group for all users and make `/opt/flutter`  group readable and writable `chmod 775` for the group as well as `chgrp flutter-group /opt/flutter` of course.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to install flutter myself and seeing which files needs write permission I recommend installing flutter in the user's home dir instead.

What I use in this case in order to save HDD space is a ZFS file system user/skeleton that I clone for each new user. The user/skeleton has all the SDK's installed. This has it's caveats though, so if you want a quick solution buy more HDD's.
Or if you can upgrade RAM but not add more HDD's you could try a file system that supports de-duplication.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Putting program code > 1 GB into each user’s home directory seems so wrong to me. It should not be the way to install software IMHO. Besides, my home directory is part of a backup plan which does not make sense for the Flutter code.